# How can I parse HTML from a url for a logged in user

Tags: html, parsing, html-parsing, jsoup

Suppose I am logged-in to youtube.
I will see videos specific to my **logged-in** user account.

So, I want to parse html of youtbe page to get all video ids of the current **logged-in** user in the browser.

I tried **Jsoup** but it parses HTML of the page as if no user is logged-in.

Hope you got my query...!!!
What could be the solution ?

Answer (score 2):

> I tried Jsoup but it parses HTML of the page as if no user is logged-in.

You have to tell Jsoup to login into Youtube. More importantly, you have to store the eventual cookie(s) provided by Youtube and reuse them for any web request to it.

Once logged in, Jsoup will be able to parse html of youtube page to get all video ids of the current logged-in user.

Here is an interesting article describing [how to login to any website with Jsoup](http://joelmin.blogspot.com.au/2016/04/how-to-login-to-website-using-jsoup-java_4.html). The article comes with an example for login to Github.

However, I write down here the whole process. Read the article for full details.

---

#### What do you need?

- A browser with developer tool enabled
- The form data used when the login process starts
- The required cookies

#### How do you process?

- Open a private browsing window.
  *This window ensures you don't have any cookies already set.*
- Fire up the developer tool bar.
  *The toolbar gives you the login form details AND the exchanges between the browser and Youtube during the whole login process.*
- Tell your browser to navigate to the Youtube login page.
  *This step will permit you to identify the first steps of the login process.*
- Login manually and see what the browser do.
  *This step allows you to identify the login exchanges (http headers, cookies etc)*
- Make Jsoup replicate the actions performed by the browser.
  *Let Jsoup do the same browser actions (send headers, store cookies, follow redirects etc) .*

#### See also:

- [Java scrap webiste with login required using Jsoup](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36493422/363573)

Comment: @Query You're welcome. Don't forget to accept your choosen answer.